# Visual Studio 2010 Fails to Install VC 9.0 Runtime

Tags: windows-7, installation, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

Those of you who've seen this: [Completely Uninstall Visual Studio 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/255852/completely-uninstall-visual-studio-2010) will know I've been having some VS2010 issues the last week or so. Well I finally managed to get my computer to a stage where I can reinstall visual studio 2010 (I uninstalled visual studio and all the c++, c# etc stuff using Repo Uninstaller (the normal uninstaller broke for most of the programs) and then removed all related registry entries, keeping a backup of course).

Well now when I try to install Visual Studio 2010 Professional from an iso mounted in Daemon Tools Lite it fails.

I'm aware of [Visual Studio 2010 fails to install with "Error occurred during setup"](https://superuser.com/questions/142595/visual-studio-2010-fails-to-install-with-error-occurred-during-setup) and have tried every method suggested (apart from uninstalling windows installer as I couldn't find how to) but I still get errors. It fails to install the VC 9.0 runtime (x86) and this is the output of the error log:

```
[03/17/11,20:26:56] VC 9.0 Runtime (x86): [2] Error: Installation failed for component VC 9.0 Runtime (x86). MSI returned error code 1601
[03/17/11,20:27:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 9.0 Runtime (x86) is not installed.
[03/17/11,20:27:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[03/17/11,20:27:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Runtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[03/17/11,20:27:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 64bit Prerequisites (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[03/17/11,20:27:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
[03/17/11,20:27:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio Macro Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[03/17/11,20:27:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[03/17/11,20:27:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[03/17/11,20:27:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
[03/17/11,20:27:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[03/17/11,20:27:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Designtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[03/17/11,20:27:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SharePoint Developer Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[03/17/11,20:27:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools was not attempted to be installed.
```

the listed error is MSI Error 1601, which is apparently: " FAILURE                 1601   The Windows Installer service could not be 
                                accessed. Contact your support personnel 
                                to verify that the Windows Installer 
                                service is properly registered."

Does that mean I need to reinstall the Windows Installer? If so how do I do that?

I'm running Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, sadly the best I could find was to completely reformat and reinstall. What I'd done was corrupt my user profile (public folders, etc) when I tried to move them off of the C drive to make more room on the solid state.

Not a very good plan, all in all and that messed up a whole lot of things.

Still can't pinpoint the exact cause, but there's the solution. Reformat and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured the Windows Installer service is enabled (and set to Manual)?

Does it start without error when you start the service manually?

You could try upgrading to [Windows Installer 4.5](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942288).

Comment: It's enabled and set to manual. Starting it seems to work fine (no errors), although running the windows installer files (I chose the x64 branch) gives me the following error: Installer Encountered an Error: 0x80040154 Class Not Registered. A quick google gives me this http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/installer-encountered-an-error-0x80040154-class/8fb5fa7c-8f41-49fa-a4c8-6044122421c0 which I'll try and get back to you

Comment: No luck, sfc /scannow bugs out too saying it cannot start the Windows Repair Service. Sadly I don't have the recovery disk on me to do a repair.

Comment: I tried installing a separate, unrelated program (windows troubleshooter for some sound issues I'm having) and that also failed so there's definitely something wrong with windows' installer.